# Using git to sync between servers

Tags: git

I am planning on using git to sync my server configuration files between my multiple game servers (I have over 32) and it takes a long time to change one file on all of the servers. I have created a git repo and plan on cloning the repo on startup. However, it needs to be a private repo as it has passwords in it. How can I clone the repo? Should I just create a new account just for the servers, add it to the repo contributors and use that account to clone?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on startup"?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1316300/how-to-sync-a-local-dir-to-server-using-git/

Answer (score 0):

### Private repos

To have private repos on [GitHub](https://github.com/pricing) you have to pay, no private repos in the free plan. As alternative you can use [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/plans) or host your own git server, may be using gitolite or something similar.

### Configuration sync

You have to clone the repo only the first time, then you can just pull from the remote repo to keep the configuration updated on all the servers. Instead of on startup you can pull by a cron entry, maybe every hour or so. If needed you can schedule in the cron also some services reboot or reload, to apply new configurations. You have also to consider that every repo git must have a root folder where all files and subfolders have to e stored. If you have two different configuration files location maybe you have to use multiple repos.

### Configuration management

The above solution is the poor-man configuration management, if you want something more structured and you have time to invest in to evaluate some configuration management solution to better fit your requirements you can check for Ansible, Salt, Puppet or Chef.