# How to sync a local dir to server using Git?

Tags: ssh, git, ftp, sync

How can I use Git to simply keep in sync a local dir with a server dir?

I'm used to FTP but it's slow and prone to errors.

I have SSH access to the server. I can run Git on the server.

I also want to avoid a third-party Git hosting service like Github or Bitbucket. I want to be able to directly upload to my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the **local machine**:

1. Initialize the directory to be synced as a Git repository

   ```
   git init
   ```

   Commit any existing code

   ```
   git add -A
   git commit -am "initial commit"
   ```
2. Set its remote to the server

   ```
   git remote set-url origin user@server:/path/to/dir/on/server
   ```

   Where

   - `user` is the username you use to SSH to your `server`. Eg. root@10.10.10.10
   - `/path/to/dir/on/server` is the directory on the server you wish to sync your changes to

   Side-note: It's advisable to go [password-less](https://www.google.com/search?q=password+less+ssh+login) for SSH logins

On the **remote machine**:

1. Initialize an empty directory on the server

   ```
   mkdir /path/to/dir/on/server
   cd /path/to/dir/on/server
   git init
   ```
2. Set its config to ignore updates to checked out branch

   ```
   git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
   ```

   This is needed because (quoting the exact error you'll get if you don't do this) "*updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match the work tree to HEAD.*" (we'll actually do just that in the next step).
3. Set up a `post-receive` [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

   Create a file `post-receive` in the `.git/hooks` directory, and open it in an editor:

   ```
   vim .git/hooks/post-receive
   ```

   Put the following in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   git --git-dir=. --work-tree=.. checkout -f
   ```

   Set its mode to executable:

   ```
   chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
   ```

   This will checkout your latest changes on the server dir whenever you push any.

- One-liner for all of above:

  ```
  dir=<dir>; mkdir $dir && cd $dir && git init && git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore && printf '#!/bin/sh\ngit --git-dir=. --work-tree=.. checkout -f' > .git/hooks/post-receive && chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
  ```

Now on the local machine you can do this:

```
git commit -am "Some changes"
git push
```

and your local dir will be synced to the server dir.

---

An additional recipe that I use often: On local machine, I keep the `origin` remote name for Github/Bitbucket which is the "home" of the project, and a special `server` remote name which is where it gets deployed. I also create a git branch (which is also named) `server` and configure it to always push to the `server` remote:

```
git config branch.server.remote server
git config remote.server.push server:master
```

This way whenever I'm on master branch it pushes to the `origin` (Github/Bitbucket etc) and when I'm on the `server` branch it pushes to the server.